# Funcion para destruir una variable

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer una función que aúne la asignación de variables con su posterior destrucción. Tenía en mente hacer algo así:

```
function setunset(&$sesion){
    $salida = $sesion;
    unset($sesion);
    return $salida;
}

$_SESSION['uno'] = '1';
$uno = setunset($_SESSION['uno']);

echo $uno; // Devuelve 1
echo $_SESSION['uno'] // Devuelve "undefined index"
```

Estoy viendo que esto tal cual no sería posible porque la destrucción de la variable se queda en el ámbito de la función y por lo tanto, `$_SESSION['uno']` seguiría existiendo. ([Documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php))

¿Hay alguna forma mas para hacerlo? ¿O me voy a tener que conformar con hacerlo a lo clásico (primero asignar y luego destruir)?

Comment: Se me ocurre 1 aún que necesito hacer unas pruebas para estar seguro de que funciona con superglobales correctamente. En cualquier caso por qué asignas y eliminas? Si es por ahorro de memoria por qué no simplemente haces una asignación por referencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa el parámetro y haz el unset de la sesión de ese parámetro, y no de su valor.

Te pongo un ejemplo en paralelo con el tuyo, la segunda función bis hace el unset de la sesión para el parámetro que le pasas:

```
function setunset(&$sesion){
    $salida = $sesion;
    unset($sesion);
    return $salida;
}
function setunsetbis($sesion){
    $salida = $_SESSION[$sesion];
    unset($_SESSION[$sesion]);
    return $salida;
}

$_SESSION['uno'] = '1';
echo $_SESSION['uno']; echo " a<br>"; // Devuelve 1
$uno = setunset($_SESSION['uno']);
echo $uno;  echo " b<br>"; // Devuelve 1
echo $_SESSION['uno'];  echo " c<br>"; // Devuelve 1
$unobis = setunsetbis('uno');
echo $unobis;  echo " d<br>"; // Devuelve 1
echo $_SESSION['uno'];  echo " e<br>"; // No está
```

Resultado

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
e
```

Si haces un `var_dump($_SESSION)` verás que no está `$_SESSION['uno']`.